# How to use access table file on every computer?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datatable, oledb

Can someone tell me how to use access table in my windows forms app. which can be opened by every computer. i tried some ways but nothing. When i run the program from other computer it drops an error [image: error photo here]

Comment: I would say this particular problem is related to the Access redistributable files not being available on the second machine.

Comment: The question is not clear.  Are you installing a copy of the access database on each machine?  Or, is the database in a network (shared) location?